What statistical test do we use to compare normal control group and experimental group?
We currently have 3 groups:
1: normal control group - no interventions
2: experimental group 200 mg/kg - induced hyperlipidemia + treatment of plant extract at 200 mg/kg
3: experimental group 400 mg/kg - induced hyperlipidemia + treatment of plant extract at 400 mg/kg
We measured their cholesterol baseline, after hyperlipidemic induction & after plant extract treatment. We did not induce hyperlipidemia on control group. We compared the hyperlipidemic state & after treatment state of groups 1 & 2 but we don't know how do we use the control value. Is it still possible to compare the control group  and the experimental group if we did not induce hyperlipdemia on the control group?

Short answer: No, I don't think it is.
Longer answer: This looks like a severe mistake in experimental design. You are now trying to compare normal controls with non-normal experimental groups. What you should have done is randomize subjects to the three groups.
At this point, I think there is no good use for your control group. If most of them had normal cholesterol, then you don't want their cholesterol to go down.
Once again, the truth of Fisher's statement:

To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often
merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps
say what the experiment died of.

is borne out.
You can, at least, compare the two treated groups.
